# Embed HTML into System.ComponentModel.DescriptionAttribute.Description

Tags: c#, wcf, .net-4.0

I'm trying to embed HTML, specifically an href, into a DescriptionAttribute, to add a link from the auto generated WCF help docs, to a more detailed SandCastle generated page describing the data structures involved.  Something along the lines of:

```
[Description(
    "Creates jobs. A detailed description of the Jobs data structure can " +
    "be found <a href=\"http://www.example.com/api/docs/jobs\">here.</a>")]
[WebInvoke(UriTemplate = "Jobs", Method = "POST")]
public Jobs CreateJobs(Jobs jobs)
{
    ...
}
```

This produces the following HTML in the resulting documentation, with my embedded HTML encoded as character entities:

```
<td>Creates jobs. A detailed description of the Jobs data structure can be found &lt;a href="http://www.example.com/api/docs/jobs\"&gt;here.&lt;/a&gt;</td>
```

Which renders **exactly** like this:

> Creates jobs. A
>   detailed description of the Jobs data structure can be found <a
>   href="http://www.example.com/api/docs/jobs\">here.</a>

But I want it to render like this:

> Creates jobs. A detailed description of the Jobs data structure
>   can be found [here.](http://www.example.com/api/docs/jobs)

I wondered whether I might be able to override the Description property to remove the character entities, so I tried this:

```
class HtmlDescriptionAttribute : System.ComponentModel.DescriptionAttribute
{
    public override string Description
    {
        get
        {
            string description = base.Description;
            //
            // Remove encoding from description here
            //
            return description;
        }
    }

    public HtmlDescriptionAttribute() : base() { }
    public HtmlDescriptionAttribute(string description) : base(description) { }
}
```

But putting a breakpoint into the overridden property, I see that at this stage it is not yet encoded.  So whatever is calling this property is presumably adding the encoding.

Does anyone have any idea whether/how it is possible to do this?

Thanks!

Comment: would it help to modify (or retrieve) the DescriptionValue rather than the Description? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.descriptionattribute(v=vs.100).aspx

Comment: @deltree - DescriptionValue seems to contain exactly the same string.  It's looking like this class has nothing to do with adding the character entities.  It is called by System.ServiceModel.Description.WebHttpBehavior.GetDescription().  I wonder if that can be overridden?

Comment: what's displaying the documentation?

Comment: A browser.  It's the WCF auto generated service docs.  My actual implementation is here: http://staging.cardeliverynetwork.com/cdntrunk/openapi/help

Comment: like this? http://andrewtokeley.net/archive/2008/10/30/adding-wsdl-documentation-to-your-wcf-services.aspx

Comment: I'm just curious if you have any control over the rendering of the documentation, because that's obviously where the html is being modified

Comment: Looks like you can.  I think this could well be the answer, but it's a bit of an undertaking just to get a link in there! http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsdesktop/WCF-Custom-Help-Page-6f5a90f0

Comment: but what are you using now is the question? is it a default generator or some toolkit?